# Weird behavior in an HTTP request with Winsock2

Tags: c++, http, winsock2

I'm trying to implement HTTP request in C++ using winsock 2.

After connecting to http://stackoverflow.com,
here's what im sending:

```
send(_socket, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.stackoverflow.com\r\n\r\n", (the length ), 0);
```

And now reading the response:

```
std::string s;
char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
int bytes = 0;

do
{
    ZeroMemory(buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH);
    bytes = recv(_socket, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH, 0);
    s.append(buffer);
} while (bytes == BUFFER_LENGTH);

return s;
```

By the way: `#define BUFFER_LENGTH 512`

Here's come the weird part, when I run the program I get only the response's headers part:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Cache-Control: public, max-age=34

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Expires: Wed, 04 Sep 2013 08:14:00 GMT

Last-Modified: Wed, 04 Sep 2013 08:13:00 GMT

Vary: *

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Date: Wed, 04 Sep 2013 08:13:26 GMT

Content-Length: 193288
```

But when I debug the read function step by step I get all the response including the content. If I put the breakpoint on the ZeroMemory() function and then continue to execute the code pressing the F10 key (Step Over) which advances one "command" at a time, the loop goes on a few times then exists and returns the full response, both the headers and the content. BUT if I put the breakpoint after the recv() function (s.append(buffer)) the loop exists immediately (after only one execution of the loop performed) and retruns just the headers.

Someone can explain to me this behavior?

What I assume is that there is some kind of a timed delay between sending the headers and the content, so when I stop before the recv() with the debugger the server have enough time to send it and then the recv() can read it all, but when I put it after, the server only had enough time to send the headers and the recv() function reads only what's already arrived and then return less than 512 bytes read, and the loop exists. Am I right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Re-read the documentation for recv. You can get a smaller amount read.

Comment: You really should check for errors or closed connections (i.e. when `bytes <= 0`). Also remember that `recv` can read *less* than requested if no more data is available at the moment.

Comment: The reason you see different behaviour depending on where the breakpoint is, is that if you put the breakpoint on or before the `recv`, the internal winsock buffer will have had time to fill up prior to you pressing F10, so it is _more likely_ (but not certain) that you will get the requested amount of data when you perform the `recv`.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption is right, as mentioned in the comment you can get less than the buffer size if the data has not arrived yet. What you should do in the loop is actually use knowledge of HTTP and for example look for `\r\n\r\n` to know when the headers have arrived, then lookup the content length and try to read that amount of data for the content. Or alternatively, since you are already on `Winsock2` use their methods `HttpSendRequest` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384247(v=vs.85).aspx) and friends - less issues if all you want to do is just send requests.

Comment: Good idea, ill try to parse it this way! And I dont want to use this functions because it's winsock specific, I want the code to be portable.